# Laravel foreach with multiple objects?

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

I have an object returned from Laravel's DB class that I pass to my view:

```
    @foreach ($appts as $appt)
        <tr>
            <td> {{ $appt->carrier }} </td>
            <td> {{ $appt->carrier }} </td>
            <td> {{ $appt->name }} </td>
            <td> {{ Format::up($appt->lines_of_authority_c) }} </td>
            <td> {{ Format::under($appt->status_c) }} </td>
            <td> {{ Format::date($appt->effective_date_c) }} </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
```

Except I have another object I need to iterate over, but if I include it under the current foreach it obviously iterates multiple times.

Is there anyway to do something like:

`@foreach($appts as $appt, $agents as $agent)`

The above?  Multiple foreaches like this?  Or some way to achieve this effect?

Or some way to merge them together?  They are both stdClass.

Answer (score 4):

This is a very old question but I had to do something similar and couldn't find anything on the internet.

I put the second @foreach inside the `<td>` element that I needed. Something like this.

```
@foreach($cars as $car)
            <tr>
                <td>{!! $car->number !!}</td>
                <td>{!! $car->color !!}</td>
                <td>{!! $car->time_of_rent!!}</td>
                <td>
                    @foreach($clients as $client)
                        @if($client->rented_car === $car->id)
                            {!! $client->name !!}
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                </td>

            </tr>
    @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

you can nest them like so:

```
@foreach ($appts as $appt)
    @foreach ($agents as $agent)
       <tr>
           <td> {{ $appt->carrier }} </td>
           <td> {{ $appt->carrier }} </td>
            <td> {{ $appt->name }} </td>
            <td> {{ Format::up($appt->lines_of_authority_c) }} </td>
            <td> {{ Format::under($appt->status_c) }} </td>
            <td> {{ Format::date($appt->effective_date_c) }} </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: That would iterate through each agent each time it iterates through one appt.

Comment: Caused an infinite loop.

Comment: @user3158900 exactly...  I need it not to do this.

Comment: aaa sorry I miss understood then.

Answer (score 0):

DB::get() should be returning an array so you should easily be able to use a for loop.  It won't be as pretty and this is assuming that you are returning them both in an order where they match and each appt would have one agent.

```
        @for ($i=0; $i < count($appts); $i++)
            <tr>
                <td> {{ $appt[$i]['carrier'] }} </td>
                <td> {{ $appt[$i]['name'] }} </td>
                <td> {{ Format::up($appt[$i]['lines_of_authority_c']) }} </td>
                <td> {{ Format::under($appt[$i]['status_c']) }} </td>
                <td> {{ Format::date($appt[$i]['effective_date_c']) }} </td>
                <td> {{ $agent[$i]['name'] }} </td>
            </tr>   
        @endfor
```

I'm not sure how you are matching them, but I would recommend setting up an actual relationship in Eloquent though.  It would be much easier to work with.

Comment: Had a massive legacy database and unfortunately using the ORM wasn't an option.  DB::get() is returning objects due to my settings.  Since it's been doing this for so long I can't change it system wide I'd have to edit everything.  I can just convert it to an array, right?

Comment: This answer cuts off after the last appt while there are still agents.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't loop through appts and then loop through agents after?  Why do they need to be done within the same loop?

Answer (score 0):

As a solution, first, you can merge two arrays using `array_merge()` function:

```
<?php $result = array_merge($appts->toArray(), $agents->toArray()); ?>
```

**Note:** For retrieving `array` from `stdClass`, you should use `toArray()` [method](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#collections).

**Important:** If you have same keys in arrays and you want to have both, you should use `array_merge_recursive()` rather than `array_merge()`.

Then, you can use `@foreach`:

```
@foreach ($result as $data)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $data->property }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: @walterjones I updated my answer, you should convert `stdClass` to `array`. i.e. `$appts->to_array()` and `$agents->to_array()` before merging them

Comment: Call to a member function to_array() on a non-object

Comment: Sorry instead of `to_array()` use `toArray()`

Comment: Be aware that this solution has potential to overwrite some properties.  For example if appt and agent both have a `name` property, the agent's name will override the appointment's name.

Comment: @user3158900 you're right. I edited my answer and added `array_merge_recursive()`

Answer (score 0):

This is an ancient one, and definitely not the latest version but the solution isn't so tricky. (*Mind you, my solution assumes you have the same column names.*)

In the controller:

```
$appts = [Query Here]
$agents = [Query Here]

$combo = [$appts, $agents]
```

Then,

```
@foreach($combo as $individualquery)
    @foreach($individualquery as $whatever)
       {{ $whatever->thing }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```